# How can I validate a matches type using CodeIgniter's Form Validation class?

Tags: php, forms

How to validate my email which is provided by user and it has to checked in database table field email..so how can I do this? The call back function is not working so any suggestions?

I have done this but not working :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email|matches[mod_register.email]');
```

Here `mod_register` is the table name and email is the field.

Answer (score 0):

Matches only checks against another form field, rather than a database field, see: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference

You could use a call back instead:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email|callback_check_email');
```

Then within your controller, add the following function:

```
/**
 * validation function for checking email exists in database
 * @param  string $email
 * @return bool
 */
public function check_email($email = NULL) {

    // if no email specified, skip
    if (empty($email)) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    // build query to check if email exists in database
    $where = array(
        'email' => $email
    );

    // run query
    $query = $this->db->get_where('mod_register', $where, 1);

    // check results
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        // matches
        return TRUE;
    }

    // no matches
    return FALSE;
}
```

See: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods